# Change the text of textview based on its ID

Tags: android, textview

I am dynamically adding a textView into a layout and giving it ID's. Based on some conditions I want to change the text of the TextView based on its ID assigned.

Something like this: personOne.setText("abcd"); where personOne.id = buttonID;

```
personOne = new TextView(this);
int buttonID =  2000 + personCount;
personOne.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.button_text);
        personOne.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        personOne.setTextSize(15);
        personOne.setText(personAdded);
        personOne.setId(buttonID);
```

Help / Suggestions much appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(yourId);
tv.setText("abcd");
```

Assuming the `TextView` is a child of the `Activity`'s content view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `buttonID` to find and manipulate `TextView` dynamically as follows:

```
TextView dynamicTextView = (TextView) findViewById(buttonID);
dynamicTextView.setText("The text you want to set");
```